# Machine learning - Score column is missing

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, ml.net

I'm trying out the ML.net framework with some random test data. My data exists of a DepartmentId (1-25) and a Body (string). I want my machine to predict the department that the body should be allocated (for example in a ticket system like Zendesk).

Using the following code, I'm receving an error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Score column is missing

I'm not sure why it says that the `Score` column is missing, as it's present in my prediction class.

Here's my setup for training the model, as well as my classes.

**Main**

```
var pipeline = new LearningPipeline();
pipeline.Add(new TextLoader(_dataPath).CreateFrom<DepartmentData>(userHeader: true, seperator: ','));
pipeline.Add(new TextFeaturizer("Features", "Body"));
pipeline.Add(new Dictionarizer("Label"));
pipeline.Add(new StochasticDualCoordinateAscentClassifier());
pipeline.Add(new PredictedLabelColumnOriginalValueConverter() { PredictedLabelColumn = "PredictedLabel" });

var model = pipeline.Train<DepartmentData, DepartmentPrediction>();
```

**DepartmentData and DepartmentPrediction**

```
public class DepartmentData
{
    [Column(ordinal: "0", name: "Label")]
    public float Department;
    [Column(ordinal: "1")]
    public string Body;
}

public class DepartmentPrediction
{
    [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
    public float Department;

    [ColumnName("Score")]
    public float[] Score;
}
```

**Example data**

```
Department, Body
1, Hello. 4 weeks ago I requested a replacement keycap for my keyboard. I still ahvent received the keycap. Perhaps you can confirm that it has been shipped?
13, I seem to have some problems when paying for you new mouse XZ-250 I'm being told that my card is not valid?
1, I just received the package I bought from you but I'm most definetly not satisfied with the shipment. The box was bended and broken when it received as well as the GPU inside. I demand that you ship a new one to me without charge. I've attached a few images of the box and the GPU here.
/* etc... */
```

**Evaluation**

```
var testData = new TextLoader(_testDataPath).CreateFrom<DepartmentData>(useHeader: true, seperator: ',');
var evaluator = new ClassificationEvaluator();
var metrics = evaluator.Evaluate(model, testData);
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `float[]` be a simple `float`?

Comment: @nvoigt No, that causes another exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Can't bind the IDataView column 'Score' of type 'Vec<R4, 11>' to field 'Score' of type 'System.Single'.'`, which is why I changed it to an array

Comment: I don't suppose you can give a quick sample of the data, can you?

Comment: Sure I can, I'll update the SO

Comment: Running this, I wasn't able to get any error. Here's [a gist](https://gist.github.com/jwood803/55dee80e1d1c7a9c254d9a317b69b3c9) of what I have and the output.

Comment: @Jon Did you finish the execution? Mine doesn't stop there, but triggers the exception after saying that it won't train a calibrator

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Very frustrating

Comment: @Detilium It did finish without any errors. How do you have the project set up?

Comment: @Jon What do you mean "how do you have tje project set up"? It's a `netcoreapp 2.1`, using `Microsoft.ML 0.3.0`. I don't know what more to tell you, since this is a very small application.

Comment: @Jon Oh wow, nevermind. It's my evalutation process that fails, and not the training part. I'm so sorry :/

Comment: @Detilium Can you post the evaluation code?

Comment: @Jon Sure, I'll update the SO. I did get it to work though, so I'm posting the evaluation code that works, not the one that didn't.

Comment: @Detilium it's good that you found an answer yourself. If possible, it would be great to see the code that wasn't working for you

Comment: Hi @Detilium I get the same error... OP, do you found a solution? My thread:

[topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335066/ml-net-score-column-is-missing)